# Adding a Progressbar to an existing Script

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I got a script to filter SMTP Log files it is separated in 2 pieces the first one

```
$result = Get-Content (path) | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            $dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }
    }
}
```

Filters for all the information I need e.g. IP, incoming Message Number, DnsName. The second one

```
$cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}
```

only counts the incoming Messages for each IP and only displays the most recent date.

Now I want to add a Progressbar, since I'm not sure if I can just combine them into one command I would probably try to add a progressbar in both commands. I read articles about the Write-progress command, but i have no idea how to involve it into already existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact combine the two commands. We'll do the grouping with `$cumulative` while parsing the lines of the log file. `$cumulative` is a `[Hashtable]`, so we can aggregate the data by *IP* and sums the number of messages on the fly. That means less operations, thus more performance.

For the progress bar, `Write-Progress` is an adequate choice. To use it here, we have to make a quick estimation of the number of lines of the log file. **We should not read at start the log file content to count the number of lines** as it will add a time costly heavy I/O operation for the sole purpose of showing a progress bar. To avoid that, we'll make an assumption of its number of lines based on the file size in bytes divided by an estimated length average of its lines. Get the file size and doing this maths is really quick, so we can afford it for the progress bar. With this estimated number of lines, we can then update a progress bar while parsing the file for a very low cost in time. While doing that, we can adjust the estimated line length to get a more accurate progress calculation for each line we read.

Here is the corresponding script, combining both operations with a a global progress bar :

```
$lfile="path"
$cumulative=@{};
# We need the file size for progress bar
$loginfo=Get-item -Path $lfile
if (!$loginfo) {
  Write-Host ("Can't find log file... : "+$lfile)
  exit 1;
}
# We'll keep a estimated line length average and the corresponding estimated number of lines of the file
# We could have started with a fixed average, but let's estimate it while rading the file
$estimateaveragelinelength=0 
$estimatelinenumber=1
$totallinelength=0 
# Counters to update the progress bar
$percent=0
$curline=0
Write-Progress -Activity ("Parsing log file "+$lfile) -Status "Start" -Id 1 -PercentComplete 0
$result = Get-Content ($lfile) | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            $dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        # We store the object we'll add to $result.
        # If you have no more usage of $result after, you should remove $result.
        $msg=[PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }
        # We do the grouping on the fly by IP, summing the number of messages
        # and keeping only the most recent date by IP
        if (!$cumulative.ContainsKey($msg.IP)) {
          $cumulative.Add($msg.IP, [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP = $msg.IP
            Messages = $msg.Messages
            DNSName = $dns
            Date    = $msg.Date
          })
        } else {
          $cumulative[$msg.IP].Messages+=$msg.Messages;
          if ($cumulative[$msg.IP].Date -lt $msg.Date) {
            $cumulative[$msg.IP].Date = $msg.Date;
          }
        }
        $msg
    }
    # Count number of lines currently read
    $curline++;
    # Adjust the estimated average line length from current line 
    # and then the corresponding estimated number of lines of the file
    if ($estimateaveragelinelength -eq 0) {
      # First read, we start with the first line length
      $estimateaveragelinelength = $_.Length
      $totallinelength = $_.Length
    } else {
      $totallinelength += $_.Length
      # Adjust the average length with the current line Length
      $estimateaveragelinelength = [math]::round($totallinelength / $curline)
    }
    # We'll ignore empty lines
    if ($estimateaveragelinelength -ne 0) {
      # Adjust the corresponding estimated number of lines of the file with the actual average line length
      # As $totallinelength  can't be greater than $loginfo.Length, we should never excess 100%, 
      # thus $estimatelinenumber can't be greater than the real number of  the lines
      $estimatelinenumber=[math]::round(($loginfo.Length / $estimateaveragelinelength))
      # Do the math and update progress bar
      $curpercent=[math]::round(($curline/$estimatelinenumber)*100);
      if ($curpercent -ne $percent) {
        $percent=$curpercent
        Write-Progress -Activity ("Parsing log file "+$lfile) -Status "In progress" -Id 1 -PercentComplete $curpercent
      }
    }
}
Write-Progress -Activity ("Parsing log file "+$lfile) -Status "Done" -Id 1 -PercentComplete 100 -Completed
$cumulative
```

Comment: HEy, this looks really good, but i cant get it to work right. Powershell tells me in line 18,19 are missing ''('' or '')'' but i cant find the spot where its missing, and he also says that the closing } for the { after ForEach-Object in line 18 is missing.

Comment: @Trippin Fixed a missing `-match`,  my bad, copy & paste failure.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much. Is the output format different to the initial commands because it is a hashtabell now instead of PSCustomObject?

Comment: @Trippin Yes, it returns now a `[Hashtable]` of `[PSCustomObject]` indexed by _IP_ instead of an `[PSCustomObject[]]` (Array of PSCustomObject). If you need an array, you can use an array cast on `$cumulative` values like  `[PSCustomObject[]]$cumulative.values` , that will return a `[PSCustomObject[]]`.